# StringBuilder lost data when convert to String

Tags: java, android, string, stringbuilder

here what's the problem

I have problem when I tried to get String from my StringBuilder

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()), 128 * 1024);
StringBuilder dataResponseSB = new StringBuilder();
String line ;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    dataResponseSB.append(line);
    if (DataFactory.DEBUG_MODE) {
        // all data here are complete
        Log.i("===LoadDataActivity","line: "+line);
    }
}
String rawdata = new String(dataResponseSB); // dataResponseSB.toString(); also not work
if (DataFactory.DEBUG_MODE) {
    // data here are lost
    Log.i("===LoadDataActivity","rawdata: "+rawdata);
}
```

(-) I receive a huge data from BufferedReader .readLine()

(-) I use Log to check and sure that I got about 5 line of 8000 Buffer Size per line **and I am very sure that I have receive all data properly**

(1) **I append each line to StringBuilder Here**

(-) after I append all the line to StringBuilder

(2) I try to convert it back to String

(-) Now, the problem, the when I check to new String here, the data have only 8192 (it should contain at least 30,000 or more)

What is the problem ? I am not sure it lost when it append to StringBuilder(1) or it lost when it convert back to String (2)

---

**I add the code that I have tried below here ,, I have tried both UTF8 and without UTF8**

```
            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            //params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, );
            params.setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE, 128 * 1024);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);


        //  HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(DataFactory.REQUEST_API_URL + "?id=" + DataFactory.USER_ID );
            // Depends on your web service

            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); //Timeout Limit
            HttpConnectionParams.setSocketBufferSize(client.getParams(), 128 * 1024);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);  
            //response.setParams(client.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE, 128 * 1024));

            //String rawdata = IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8");
           // String rawdata = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            String rawdata = getResponseBody(response.getEntity());

            //Scanner s = new Scanner(response.getEntity().getContent()).useDelimiter("\\A");
            //String rawdata = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";


            /*

            //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            // ===================

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()), 128 * 1024);
            StringBuilder dataResponseSB = new StringBuilder();
            String line ;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                dataResponseSB.append(line);
                if (DataFactory.DEBUG_MODE) {
                    Log.i("===LoadDataActivity","line: "+line);
                }
            }
            dataResponseSB.trimToSize();
            String rawdata = new String(dataResponseSB);

            /*
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            int c;
            while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
                sb.append((char)c);
                if (DataFactory.DEBUG_MODE) {
                    //Log.i("===LoadDataActivity","line: "+line);
                }
            }
            */
```

Comment: Use `String json = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())`

Comment: Have you tried to insert print/log statements to test your guesses?

Comment: @Raghunandan have tried both EntityUtils.toString and IOUtils.toString

Comment: @Raghunandan I'm Sorry, your code is also correct, it because of my stupid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is the problem:

```
Log.i("===LoadDataActivity","rawdata: "+rawdata);
```

You're assuming that a log entry *can* include all of your data - I believe each log entry is limited to 8192 characters.

I suggest you log `rawdata.length()` and you'll see that it's actually got all of the data - it's just logging it that's failing.

Comment: Really thanks, this is the actual problem of my code,
instead of this, I found the length of beffered I got has increase by 1 (some thing lime 40,000 + 1) , don't know what it wrong

Comment: Best practice is to do this: `Log.i("===LoadDataActivity","rawdata: ["+rawdata + "]");` (notice the brackets around the data).  This way, it would have been apparent that it was not the raw data that was truncated, and the StringBuilder would be 'innocent'.

Answer (score 1):

try this,,

```
public String getResponseBody(final HttpEntity entity) throws IOException, ParseException {

        if (entity == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("HTTP entity may not be null");
        }

        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

        if (instream == null) {
            return "";
        }

        if (entity.getContentLength() > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(

                    "HTTP entity too large to be buffered in memory");
        }

        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream, HTTP.UTF_8));

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

        } finally {
            instream.close();
            reader.close();
        }
        System.out.println("GEN END : " + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        return buffer.toString();

    }
```

Comment: I copy/paste your code and use in it
the result still show only 8192 
Thanks,

Comment: I'm Sorry, your code is also correct, it because of my stupid

Answer (score 1):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem...

StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), HTTP.UTF_8));

String line = null;
try {
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
    }

} finally {
    instream.close();
    reader.close();
}
System.out.println("Buffer : " + buffer.toString());
```

Comment: I copy/paste your code and use in it the result still show only 8192 Thanks

Comment: I'm Sorry, your code is also correct, it because of my stupid